# Microsoft 2FA triggered without password?

Tags: account-security, multi-factor

Currently, I have someone attempting to login to my microsoft account. Upon looking at my activity history I am now seeing almost a hundred failed sign in attempts with the reason being "incorrect password entered". However, recently I have been getting Microsoft Authenticator popups on my phone to sign in to my account (not created by me). Looking at this further I can see that it isnt required for a person to have the password in order to trigger a 2FA request. You just need to click "Other ways to sign in". All this person has is my email but they are able to trigger popups on my end. How is this the case? Every other platform I know requires the username and password to be entered before 2FA is triggered. Is there anything I can do to stop this person sending notifications to my phone.[image]

Comment: For some services I have, some times I am asked for my username, then a sign push gets sent to my phone, and after that I get asked for the password. So if someone have your email, this can happen.

Comment: I think you can turn on/off "passwordless authentication" and "two-step verification" in your account settings.   You can also change the backup e-mail associated with it in case you forget your password.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works as I haven't encountered this before... but if you add the attacker IP or even Country to a conditional access block policy that might work.  Of course, even if it does, he can easily bypass via VPN.

You could whitelist your IP range, but you risk locking yourself out.  Give yourself backup options here like an exempt break-glass account.  Still, I'm uncertain where in the AAD auth flow the IP is checked, so I'm uncertain if this will work.